# Unit testing AngularJS application with karma-browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, browserify, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test an AngularJS/Browserify application via karma-browserify. Ultimately, when I run my gulp karma task, I get the error `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it...`

My *gulpfile.js* has the task

```
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    new karma.Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
    }, done).start();
});
```

My *karma.conf.js* includes

```
{
  // ...
  frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
  files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'spec/**/*.js'
  ],
  preprocessors: {
    'spec/**/*.js': [ 'browserify' ]
  },
  browserify: {
    debug: true
  }
  // ...
}
```

I define my module in a *main.js* that includes

```
require('angular').module('myApp', [
  //...lots of `require`s for each dependency...
]);
```

I define my controller in a *MainCtrl.js* that looks like

```
function MainCtrl(/*...deps...*/) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.foo = 'bar';
}

module.exports = MainCtrl;
```

then register the controller elsewhere like

```
var app = require('angular').module('myApp');
app.controller('MainCtrl', [/*...deps...*/, require('./MainCtrl')]);
```

Finally my test looks like

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    describe('MainCtrl', function() {
        var ctrl;

        beforeEach( angular.mock.module('myApp') );

        beforeEach( inject( function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
        }));

        it('should be defined', function() {
            expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
}());
```

## Workaround

The workaround I have is to add my `main.js` file to *karma.conf.js*

```
files: [
  'js/main.js', // ADDED: Defines the app and `require`s angular
  'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'spec/**/*.js'
],
preprocessors: {
  'js/main.js': ['browserify'], // ADDED
  'spec/**/*.js': ['browserify']
}
```

and everything works. But I thought I wasn't supposed to add my source files to karma (at least not with karma-browserify). Is this the right way to set up my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 'workaround' is the desired way to use `karma-browserify`.

[`preprocessors` definition](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/preprocessors.html) specifies which of the included files should be processed by which preprocessor but does not include them:

> The keys of the preprocessors config object are used to filter the
>   files specified in the files configuration.

it is [`files` definition](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html) that actually includes the files:

> The files array determines which files are included in the browser and
>   which files are watched and served by Karma.

Answer (score 0):

Files tells Karma which files it should load relative to the base path. These are:

All test related libraries
Our source code to test
The tests themselves